# Get Value from a Input field Angular With Code

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, angular14

I want to take values from input to a function to alert
here is my html

```
<div class="container p-5 ">
  <input #titleInput *ngIf="isClicked"  type="text"  class="col-4"><br>
  <button (click)="OnClick()" class="btn btn-primary col-2 ">
    Show 
  </button>
  <button (click)="Send(titleInput.value)" class="btn btn-success col-2 m-3">
    Send
  </button>
</div>
```

and here is my componet.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

Send(data: any) {
  alert(data)

}

OnClick() {
  this.isClicked=true;
}
  title = 'demoproject1';
  isClicked=false;
}
```

I want to get value from input field and I want get value into components function

Answer (score 1):

Create Variable to store input value: 
component.ts

```js
...
export class AppComponent {
input: string;
...
```

Add FormsModule to your module.ts if not already imported
module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

setup ngModel on your HTML: 
html:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input" ></-input>
```

**Important:**
Dont forget to add a Route to the component in your app-routing.module.ts

[ngModel Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('titleInput') titleInput: 
ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Put your logic here ...
}
```

i put the code here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4hcqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html